# Subset with list in linear model

Tags: r

I am having troubles with using `subset` which involves lists in my linear model. One of two things happen, when I use `lapply` I get `object 'x' not found`. When I use `mapply` I get that `object 'y' not found`. For some reason neither variable is working in `subset`.

Here are my two approaches:

```
library(faraway)
data(savings)

form <- "sr ~ pop75 + dpi + ddpi + pop15"
#approach one
lapply(label_res, function(x){
     lm(form, savings, subset = (!row.names(savings) %in% x))
})
#output does not change for all linear models

#approach two
form_list<-rep(form, 4) %>% as.list()
mapply(function(x, y)
    {lm(x, savings, subset=(!row.names(savings) %in% y))}, form_list, label_res)
>Error in row.names(savings) %in% y : object 'y' not found
```

However this does work:

```
library(faraway)
data(savings)

form <- "sr ~ pop75 + dpi + ddpi + pop15"
#approach one
lapply(label_res, function(x){subset(savings, !row.names(savings) %in% x) %>%
    lm(form, .)
})
```

Here s `label_res`:

```
list(pop75 = c("Ireland", "Japan"), dpi = c("Ireland", "Sweden", 
"United States"), ddpi = "Libya", pop15 = c("Japan", "Libya"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way that `lm` internally calls `model.frame`. It tries to evaluate the arguments in the parent frame, which means that it is trying to find an object called `x` in the global environment, when one doesn't exist. There are various ways round this. The easiest is to subset the data frame you pass to `lm` in the first place, which actually requires less typing than using `subset` anyway:

```r
lapply(label_res, function(x) {
  lm(form, savings[!row.names(savings) %in% x,])
})
```

Another, less satisfactory way if you really want to use the `subset` argument, is to write `x` into the calling environment with each iteration

```r
lapply(label_res, function(x) {
  x <<- x
  lm(form, savings, subset = !row.names(savings) %in% x)
})
```

I prefer the first option since it doesn't have any side effects in the calling frame, but they both produce the same output:

```r
#> $pop75
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = form, data = savings[!row.names(savings) %in% x, 
#>     ])
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)        pop75          dpi         ddpi        pop15  
#>  26.0381140   -1.4257571   -0.0002792    0.3547081   -0.4078521  
#> 
#> 
#> $dpi
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = form, data = savings[!row.names(savings) %in% x, 
#>     ])
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)        pop75          dpi         ddpi        pop15  
#>   29.009000    -2.216356     0.000589     0.443409    -0.469873  
#> 
#> 
#> $ddpi
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = form, data = savings[!row.names(savings) %in% x, 
#>     ])
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)        pop75          dpi         ddpi        pop15  
#>  24.5240460   -1.2808669   -0.0003189    0.6102790   -0.3914401  
#> 
#> 
#> $pop15
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = form, data = savings[!row.names(savings) %in% x, 
#>     ])
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)        pop75          dpi         ddpi        pop15  
#>   20.580204    -0.644662    -0.000448     0.516628    -0.310588
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>